# Filltering Trello Data With Since

Tags: trello

We are trying to filter our trello data according to the date that card was created.
In the [API](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-field) it states that you should use since. As soon as the field is entered no data is returned.

Is there a special date format that is needed?

URL Format: https://trello.com/1/board/[Bord_Id]/cards/All?fields=name,labels,idList&since=2013-01-01&open&key=[application_key]&token=[optional_auth_token]

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten the "since" parameter to work by giving it in the same format that their timestamps are returned in.  Their timestamps look like this: "2013-09-17T21:15:03.810Z".  When you give it a value for "since", you don't have to include seconds (or fractional seconds).  And you don't have to include the "Z" (which, I have just learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706688/what-does-the-z-mean-in-unix-timestamp-120314170138z), means "Zulu time", which is the same as UTC), so you could give it "2013-09-17T21:15" (I'm not sure if it defaults to some other time zone though).