# How to convert time stamp string "2014-07-20T05:11:49.988Z" into POSIXt in R?

Tags: r, timestamp

How to convert time stamp string “2014-07-20T05:11:49.988Z” into POSIXt in R?

I want to know why the second is represented in 3 decimel places? also what is the meaning of appending the 'Z' at the end of time stamp?
Can anybody know how this string can be converted into time in R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Z" is [shorthand for UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706688/what-does-the-z-mean-in-unix-timestamp-120314170138z). You can parse this in base R with

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2014-07-20T05:11:49.998Z", 
    format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="GMT")
```

Note that you generally either use POSIXct or POSIXlt rather than POSIXt directly (both have POSIXt as a base class)

Comment: `POSIXt` is a virtual class, so you can't actually use `POSIXt` directly.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That's by convention only, right? R doesn't have a way to specify/enforce a virtual class (despite what the `?DateTimeClasses` page says)

Comment: Right, you can make a `POSIXt` object `p <- structure(1405833110, class="POSIXt", tzone="GMT")`, but I doubt you would be able to do much with it.

Answer (score 2):

The `lubridate` package has very robust parsers that I tend to prefer over manual specification of the `format` in base R

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

(t <- ymd_hms("2014-07-20T05:11:49.998Z"))
#> [1] "2014-07-20 05:11:49 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Making sure that the milliseconds that aren't printed aren't lost either:

```r
second(t)
#> [1] 49.998
```