# extracting hour and minute from character column in r

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, data-analysis, posixlt

I have the following data frame,the data set is already imported from a database table and created_at column has character type:

```
sale_id      created_at
1               2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z
2               2016-05-30T12:50:58.184Z
3               2016-05-23T10:22:18.858Z
4               2016-05-27T09:20:15.158Z
5               2016-05-21T08:30:17.337Z
6               2016-05-28T07:41:14.361Z
```

How can i extract only hour and minute from created_at column , preferably using base r libraries? i need to paste  hour and minute together later and put it as a new column.

Comment: `substr(df$created_at, 12, 16)` or if you don't need the `:` then `gsub(substr(df$created_at, 12, 16))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the convenient functions in `lubridate` to convert the `character` column to `DateTime` and extract the hour and minute with `format`

```
library(lubridate)
v1 <- ymd_hms("2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z")
format(v1, "%H:%M")
#[1] "05:53"
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
format(as.POSIXct("2016-05-28T05:53:31.042z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),  "%H:%M")
#[1] "05:53"
```

---

Other options include with `gsub`

```
gsub(".*T|:\\d+\\..*", "", "2016-05-28T05:53:31.042z")
#[1] "05:53"
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it not using lubridate?

Comment: @sanaz Yes, it is possible

Comment: How it is possible?

Comment: @akrun Looks like we both used this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207382/how-to-convert-time-stamp-string-2014-07-20t051149-988z-into-posixt-in-r Might be a dup then.

Comment: @Hack-R I didn't refer to it, but you can dupe it if that is a dupe

Answer (score 1):

Using only base R libraries:

```
format(as.POSIXct("2016-05-28T05:53:31.042z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),  "%H:%M")
```

> 05:31

It appears that's UTC format. For more details on parsing that format see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207382/how-to-convert-time-stamp-string-2014-07-20t051149-988z-into-posixt-in-r).

Let me show it using `Sys.Date()` for an example as well:

```
format(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "America/New_York"), "%H:%M")
```

> 08:15

Using the infinitely better `lubridate` library:

```
require(lubridate)
minute(ymd_hms("2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z"))
```

> 53

```
second(ymd_hms("2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z"))
```

> 31.042

Comment: That's why i asked preferably base R packages

Comment: @sanaz OK no problem, I have updated the question and will add a bit more to it as well

Comment: @sanaz Right that's why I was saying I didn't know what timezone it is but I would update it (and I added another example with Sys.Date). I figured out that it's GMT though and updated it again.