# Sum aggregation in elastic search

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data (df) in this format. I need to covert the Time stamp (tweetCreatedAt) into a date object so that I can further manipulate the data.

```
    tweetCreatedAt                comment_text
1   2014-05-17T00:00:49.000Z      @truthout: India Elects Hard-Right Hindu 

2   2014-05-17T00:00:49.000Z     Narendra Modi is welcome to visit US !
```

Any help?

I have tried the following

```
df[,1] <- lapply(df[,1],function(x) as.POSIXct(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

But now I'm getting the dates only and not the actual time.

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(yourdata[,1], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` or if you need a 'Date' class, just do `as.Date(yourdata[,1],  '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: `Z` stands for UTC time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706688/what-does-the-z-mean-in-unix-timestamp-120314170138z - so make sure you specify this: `as.POSIXct(data$tweetCreatedAt, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz="UTC")` at the end

Comment: I'm getting the following error. 

'Error in as.POSIXct.default(df$tweetCreatedAt, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",  : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$tweetCreatedAt' to class “POSIXct”'

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: I simply have no idea about this. The error is 
"do not know how to convert 'df$tweetCreatedAt' to class “POSIXct”"

Comment: Can you try after specifying the `origin` i.e. `as.POSIXct(df1[,1], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', origin='1970-01-01',tz='UTC')`

Comment: According to the format and to `?strptime` a shorter format is `%FT%T`. A  `dput(head(df))` would help giving the class of the tweetCreatedAt column too.

Comment: Not helping either :/

Comment: Did you get that error by applying @akrun 's solution to your initial dataset, or to the example you provided? I have a feeling that some elements of your "tweetCreatedAt" column are lists.

Comment: Nope. No luck. They might be list. Can we work them out?

Comment: @AkshayJangra That's why I added in my comment: "A dput(head(df)) would help giving the class of the tweetCreatedAt column too" ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but it's a possible one.
As I've mentioned in my comment, the elements of a column could be values, or lists, due to the process that generated this dataset.
Check this example:

```
# simplified example
dt = read.table(text = "tweetCreatedAt  comment_text
1   2014-05-17T00:00:49.000Z      @truthout 
2   2014-05-19T00:00:49.000Z     Narendra", header=T)

dt$tweetCreatedAt = as.character(dt$tweetCreatedAt)

# data set looks like
dt

#             tweetCreatedAt comment_text
# 1 2014-05-17T00:00:49.000Z    @truthout
# 2 2014-05-19T00:00:49.000Z     Narendra

as.POSIXct(dt$tweetCreatedAt, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

# [1] "2014-05-17 00:00:49 BST" "2014-05-19 00:00:49 BST"


# let's manually change this element to a list
dt$tweetCreatedAt[2] = list(c("2014-05-19T00:00:49.000Z","2014-05-20T00:00:49.000Z"))

# data set now looks like this
dt

#                                       tweetCreatedAt comment_text
# 1                           2014-05-17T00:00:49.000Z    @truthout
# 2 2014-05-19T00:00:49.000Z, 2014-05-20T00:00:49.000Z     Narendra

as.POSIXct(dt$tweetCreatedAt, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

# Error in as.POSIXct.default(dt$tweetCreatedAt, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") : 
#   do not know how to convert 'dt$tweetCreatedAt' to class “POSIXct”
```

Comment: Yup. I get the your answer. Thanks. But can I do the same while using     lapply function? Because I have list with more than 1000 time stamps

Comment: Thanks, I got the desired results.