# Timezone date format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have to convert a `SYSDATE` date to a specific date format. That format must be something like this: `'2016-11-23T15:12:48Z'`. I think this is a weird date format but is the requirements that I have.

This must be a date to send in a Web Service message.

In Oracle (12c or 11g) I have some function to transform a date in this specific format? Thanks.

Comment: [to_char()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) - it's not a "weird" format though. This is an ISO format that includes the timezone

Comment: If I recall correctly it's the ISO-8601 standard but, well, some people even complaint about the metric system :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will give you ISO-8601 mentioned in comment:

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tzm') isodt from dual;
```

If you really want `Z` instead of timezone you can use:

```
    select to_char(cast(systimestamp as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC',
               'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"')
    from dual;
```

Comment: The `Z` post script on the ISO-8601 indicates that the timestamp is from the UTC time zone (Zulu-time). If `SYSDATE` is not UTC then it will need to be converted to the correct time zone.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. I haven't known that. I've added cast to UTC to amend it.

Comment: @Kacper or you could use the pre-defined `sys_extract_utc()` function which does the work for you.

Comment: @Boneist Yes I've seen your answer. Thank you.

Comment: `TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', '...')` is wrong. This works only if your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is equal to your database server time zone. You must use `TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP), '...')`

Answer (score 4):

Since the ["Z" in the timestamp format you're after means "This is in UTC"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706777/4479309), you should first make sure your sysdate is returned in UTC. You can do this by using systimestamp and [sys_extract_utc()](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E26088_02/functions186.htm) like so:

```
select to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"') dt_as_utc
from dual;

DT_AS_UTC
--------------------
2016-11-28T10:33:49Z
```