# Query to print date in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ format in oracle and postgresql

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

Is there a way to print date in the below format in both oracle and postgresql

```
2018-05-18’T’13:30:42.000+0000
```

Comment: Store the values in an appropriate date/time value, use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the resulting value into a `String`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841489/timezone-date-format-in-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD"''T''"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM') FROM dual;
```

returns

```
2018-05-27'T'02:45:22.152+0200
```