# Log levels in Stackdriver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, stackdriver, app-engine-flexible

I have a simple service in GCP Flex:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    logging.debug('hello')
    return 'hello'
```

Looking at Stackdriver this log is shown in `stderr`, like this:

> 15:32:38.000  DEBUG:root:hello

A couple of problems with this:

- timestamps should have milisecond precision (always `.000`)
- logs cannot be filtered using stackdriver log level filter

Is there any way to address these issues? Does `logging` need to be configured in some way?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to see logs in `stackdriver` just use print (in Python) or `System.out.print(java)` command in your code. It will appear in the `Stackdriver`.

eg: `print ("hello")`  or

```
System.out.println("hello");
```

And the time stamp is in Zulu format. (eg: `timestamp: "2018-07-18T10:16:46Z"`).

you can get an idea by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706688/what-does-the-z-mean-in-unix-timestamp-120314170138z).

Comment: I downvoted because using the logging module is better than using print and `System.out.println` is java not python
I recommend this article https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/formatting-python-logs-for-stackdriver-5a5ddd80761c for better Stackdriver integration

Comment: Print examples are given for both python & java. AND when this answer is posted (in 2018) Stackdriver had a bug. At that time if you wanted to filter out the logs, You had to do that way. Now that is fixed. @firescar96