# Gmail markup metadata dectects wrong dates

Tags: google-schemas

I have a problem with the hotel reservation email markup system described in [this page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation#microdata)

I've included the metadata in an hotel reservation email but it doesn't detect the checkin and checkout dates correctly.

This is the metadata I used.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LodgingReservation">
<meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="111111">
<link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationPending">
<div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><meta itemprop="name" content="Guillem Test"></div>
<div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LodgingBusiness">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Apartamentos La Solana">
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="-">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="-">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="-">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="-">
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="-">
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="telephone" content="-">
</div>
<meta itemprop="checkinDate" content="2021-01-26T16:00:00+00:00">
<meta itemprop="checkoutDate" content="2021-01-27T11:00:00+00:00">
<meta itemprop="bookingTime" content="2020-09-17T00:00:00+00:00">
```

As you can see, it indicates that check-in and check-out dates are 2021-01-26 and 2021-01-27 respectively, but in gmail, the check-out date detected is 2020-01-28. It always adds one day to the check-out date as you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRKJI.png).

It happens with every reservation email I send.

I also tried replacing checkinDate and checkoutDate by checkinTime and checkoutTime as it says [here](https://schema.org/LodgingReservation) but still doesn't work.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to the timezone difference. Try setting your dates to GMT/UTC using Z(ulu): [What does the 'Z' mean in Unix timestamp '120314170138Z'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706688/what-does-the-z-mean-in-unix-timestamp-120314170138z)

Comment: I tried setting the dates using Z in timestamp but still does not work. Any other possible solution?

Thank you